# How to get Month and year from LocalDate JAVA 8?

Tags: java, parsing, localdate

I need to get the month and the year from a LocalDate

```
        String moisExtraction = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).toString();

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM");
        LocalDate dateExtraction = LocalDate.parse(moisExtraction, formatter);
```

But i am always getting a parse error.

I am a bigenner with java and i did not found the solution for my problem.

Comment: you mean , you want to get LocalDate in yyyyMM format ?

Comment: the string is something like `2021-04-20`, it cannot be parsed as `yyyyMM` - you already have a `LocalDate`, which is a combination of year, month and day. If you want it **formatted** as `yyyyMM`, use `formatter.format(l)`

Comment: yes exactly, I want to get LocalDate in yyyyMM please

Comment: You cannot convert string yyyyMM to LocalDate because date is missing

Comment: you mean that i need to consider my yyyyMM as a string not a localdate ? i want to say i cannot use my yyyyMM as a localdate so i am obliged to use it as string

Comment: Yes @sr123. It cannot be LocalDate

Comment: again, use `formatter.format(LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1))` (parse: convert string to some object; format: convert some object to string (representation))